# Make first column fixed and next column scrollable in html Table

Tags: html, css

I have a table with only two columns . i want to make first column is fixed and next column scrollable in all the rows..it should be horizontally scrollable as a whole .. not individual columns

There can be hundreds of rows.    .

I have a demo code here in [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yw679/1/)

I dont have much exposure to css styling.

Comment: Scrollable horizontally or vertically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>You could use CSS `overflow:auto;`, as in http://jsfiddle.net/Yw679/2/</strike>

If I understand correctly, you want the entire left column to be static, and the entire right column (including the header) to be horizontally scrollable. Is that correct?

If so, it's not possible with one table. But with a bit of extra code, it's possible with two tables like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Yw679/6/

Comment: whole column should be scrollable.. not only the first th

Answer (score 3):

What you're searching for is called **"frozen columns"**.

See a jqGrid [demo here](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) that implements column freezing in version **4.3**. It's quite a versatile grid plugin and definitely worth a try(if you haven't already, that is).

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Yw679/3/

```
th{
  display :inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

th:first-child{
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

​

Comment: in every row second column should be horizontally scrollable . not only in first row. it should be scrollable as a whole .. not individual columns

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do something like this example

https://www.datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/examples/initialisation/left_right_columns.html

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use a single table along with two column fixed and other are scrollable.

`Here is the` [link](https://jsfiddle.net/brianlmerritt/8c5jgs4b/).