# HTML Table Freeze Column breaks layout

Tags: css, html-table

I've been trying to get the layout in the following link to work correctly:
    http://jsfiddle.net/Tc5Xk/

Can someone help with this ?

```
div.dashboardBox {
 border: 1px solid #999999;
 width: 45%;
 margin-right: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 float: left;
}
div.dashboardBoxBody {
 padding: 8px;
 height: 200px;
 overflow: auto;
 margin-left : 5em;    
}
table.standardTable {
  position: static;
  width: 95%;    
}
.standardTable th {
 font-size: 11px;
 background-color: #888888;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align: left;
 border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
}
#header_detail {
  text-align: left;
  position:absolute;    
  left : 0;    
}
<div class="dashboardBox">
<div class="dashboardBoxBody">
    <table style="width:200%" class="standardTable">
        <tr>
            <th id="header_detail">Location</th>
            <th id="header">Jan-13</th>
            <th id="header">Feb-13</th>
            <th id="header">Mar-13</th>
            <th id="header">Apr-13</th>
            <th id="header">May-13</th>
            <th id="header">Jun-13</th>
            <th id="header">Jul-13</th>
            <th id="header">Aug-13</th>
            <th id="header">Sep-13</th>
            <th id="header">Oct-13</th>
            <th id="header">Nov-13</th>
            <th id="header">Dec-13</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="header_detail">Australia</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="header_detail">California</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="header_detail">Hyderabad</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="header_detail">Los Angeles</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="header_detail">Colorado</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="header_detail">Denver</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="header_detail">Nevada</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="header_detail">Stockholm</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="header_detail">Switzerland</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="header_detail">Brussels</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="header_detail">Paris</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="header_detail">Calicut</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="header_detail">Leh</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="header_detail">Denmark</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="header_detail">Constaninople</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="header_detail">Istanbul</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="header_detail">Las Vegas</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
            <td id="detail">80.5%</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Jag96/gPRqa/

Comment: @Joe_G : The left column needs to stay when horizontally scrolled.

Comment: Read these, it might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11815882/make-first-column-fixed-and-next-column-scrollable-in-html-table, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402295/html-table-with-horizontal-scrolling-first-column-fixed, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312236/how-do-i-create-an-html-table-with-fixed-frozen-left-column-and-scrollable-body/17557830#17557830

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in this line

```
#header_detail {
    text-align: left;
    position:absolute;  // This line   
    left : 0;    
}
```

If you take out position: absolute; you will get all city's in your area.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tc5Xk/2/)

Comment: Doing so will not freeze the first column

Comment: I found similer situation. Here is code with e.x. You should take idea from here.

http://jsfiddle.net/sgcer/

Comment: You can see from the link you've sent that the last row before scrolling in the left column does not have a matching one on the right side.

Comment: You just need to manage both divs heights, to get match in both sides. Like this. http://jsfiddle.net/sgcer/438/

Answer (score 0):

```
div.dashboardBoxBody {
 padding: 8px;
 height: 200px;
 overflow: auto;
 // margin-left : 5em;    
}

#header_detail {
  text-align: left;
  // position:absolute;   
  left : 0;    
}
```

You need to remove the position absolute **AND** the margin-left of your div to get the same result without the overflow.

Comment: Doing so will not freeze the first column

Comment: Oh, ok. I didn't get it, quite a weird request. :) Just give a few more information on what you're looking for next time.

Comment: The first column comes out of the table in the link I've provided. You can see that if you scroll left, the first column stays intact. So, my question clearly states that while I'm trying to freeze or fix one column, it breaks the table layout.

Comment: I thought the problem was about things being messed up at the bottom. I guess you'll need at least two tables to do something.